# From outside the cluster, unable to reach MyApp (client --> <nodeIP>:<nodePort> --> Service --> Pod --> MyApp)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

**Issue**: From outside cluster, exposing service via NodePort, I am unable to reach the application.
I should be to get a response from MyApp: From my mac client (http://nodeIP:nodePort/api/users) --> node (nodePort) --> service (endPoints) -- pod --> MyApp (in container)

**Setup**:

- OS: Mac and DockerDesktop using KIND, created cluster (1-master,
  2-workers)
- deployed simple app and able to 'kubectl exec myPod --
  curl http://localhost/api/users' <-- this does work
- Then created 'service' with type:NodePort (auto picked by k8)
- Supposedly from my Mac (client), I should be able to reach MyApp but trying to 'curl (http://nodeIP:nodePort/api/users)' just times out.

**Request**:
Not sure what is missing: is it firewall blocking it, is there a port forwarding missing, something else ... from my computer trying to
'curl http://:/api/users' times out.

side note: I know I can use other methods like ingress.  For now, I am trying to learn and figure out why NodePort method isn't working.

Comment: What are you using for the `nodeIP` in your URLs?  Have you configured kind's networking layer at all?

Comment: can you post some things like `kubectl describe svc` and `kubect describe pod -o wide`. Also might be good to see any yaml you have.

Comment: the fact that `localhost` works and `NodePort` doesn't could mean the service is listening only on localhost inside the container -- the tie-breaker would be whether you can access that Pod from another Pod within your cluster (and then the same experiment against the Service from within the cluster)

Answer (score 0):

Docker for Mac runs in a hyperkit Linux VM and not on your actual Mac. So with [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/), every node is a container, and unfortunately, you won't be able to connect to the NodePort from your Mac.

The workaround is to connect from the Docker VM or from a container with the same networking space as the VM.

```sh
$ docker run --rm -it --net host alpine sh
# curl http://<the-ip-address-from-a-node>:<NodePort>/api/users
```

If you'd like browser access, another way is to [`kubectl proxy ...`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls) from your Mac to reach the service. Or [`kubectl port-forward svc/service-name <localport>:<serviceport>`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) to the service.